# JFoenix JFXTreeTableView column heading alignment

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, jfoenix

I am writing a JavaFX application in which I am creating a table using the `JFXTreeTableView` component from the JFoenix library. By default, the column headings are center aligned.

I would like the column headings to be center left aligned. I have tried using the following CSS to do so:

```
.tree-table-view .column-header .label {
   -fx-alignment: CENTER_LEFT;
}
```

However, the above CSS has no effect on the alignment of the column headings which remain center aligned.

Does the `JFXTreeTableView` component facilitate the alignment of column headings? If so, what is the correct code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS can be used

```
.tree-table-view .column-header > StackPane{
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
}
```